# Python script to extract content from a file

Tags: python, xml, text-files

StackOverflow has similar questions to this but my query could not be resolved somehow. I want to extract the content in the tags content, text and correct feedback and incorrect feedback

```
<content ID="0">Which of the following are objectives of Sourcing?</content>
     <cyu ID="1">
        <text id="1" Type="true">Simplify the management of the procurement process</text>
        <text id="2" Type="false">Perform long-term contract management</text>
        <text id="3" Type="true">Select, develop, and maintain sources of supply</text>
        <text id="4" Type="false">Calculate maintenance and servicing costs</text>
        <text id="5" Type="true">Enable maintenance of inventory for continuous production</text>
        <correctFeedback>Great! You made the correct choice. </correctFeedback>
        <incorrectFeedback>You made an incorrect choice. </incorrectFeedback>
     </cyu>
```

The code I have used is with open("m01_004_000.xml") as infile:

```
with open("whole.txt","w") as outfile:
    collector = []
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith("<content ID ="">"):
            collector = []
        collector.append(line)
        if line.startswith("<correctFeedback>"):
            for outline in collector:
                outfile.write(outline)
```

but this shows a blank whole.txt. What could be wrong? any other way to do it?

Comment: If you're trying to parse XML, there are modules to help you do that. You don't need to (and probably shouldn't) be writing your own parsing code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems:

1. Your lines are not starting as you expect, there are whitespaces before the text. So you should do:

   ```
   line = line.strip()
   ```

   after

   ```
   for line in infile:
   ```

   in order to remove the whitespaces.
2. The syntax: `"<content ID ="">"` creates the string `<content ID =>` because of the repeated quotes, and you have no line that start like that.
3. You should really use the module [`xml`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.html) to parse xml files.